# Filter the query result

Tags: mysql, join, greatest-n-per-group, distinct

I have one query by which I am getting duplicate ComapnyID and I want to filter that and remove duplicate ComapnyID but don't want change the order by report.

```
table 1 reports
```

[image]

```
Table 2 Company
```

[image]
Here is the query

```
SELECT c.CompanyID,c.`CategoryID`,c.`CompanyName`,  r.`CreatedDate`,r.`ReportID` FROM `company`c
JOIN reports r ON r.CompanyID = c.CompanyID
WHERE r.ProductServiceID= 14 AND c.RegionID=1 AND c.IsActive = 1
ORDER BY r.`ReportID` DESC ;
```

```
Result 1
```

[image]

I want to remove the 2nd duplicate ComapnyID in result

I have tried these queries

```
Distinct 
Inner join
Group by with having
```

if I change the query and get distinct data than the order gets change which I don't want.

```
Result 2
```

[image]
What am I missing here? Can any of you resolve this issue?

Thanks

Comment: Marked records are NOT duplicates. The records are duplicates if and only if ALL fields in them have the same values. If at least one filed have different values - that pair is NOT a duplicate. *I want to remove the duplicate id in result* If you want to select only one record from such pair (or more) you must create/formulate a criteria which allows to select what record must be stored and what record(s) must be eliminated.

Comment: @Akina thanks man, I tried and didn't get the solution , that's why I posted here.

Comment: Nevertheless I do not see clearly and unambiguously formulated criteria which allows to determine what record from "duplicates" must be selected. Until it occures nobody can help you.

Comment: @Akina I change the query and remove the duplicate values but now why that order by is not working?

Comment: *but now why that order by is not working?* What ordering? where, in what screenshot? I don't understand... be more precise, please.

Comment: @Akina see the result 1 and result 2, Order has been change for the end result and both results are different.

Comment: These results makes sense for you - you can see the whole result. I can see only the part which you show. And these parts do not match each other. Restrict the output selecting 5-7 `CompanyID` values with and without duplicates and show both outputs which will match each other.

Comment: You use `DISTINCT .. ORDER BY CreatedDate`, but this field is not included into the output. Now look - there was 2 records with the same values for all fields in output and different `CreatedDate` values. Distinct gets one record from this pair. Now please predict what `CreatedDate` value of two possible values will be used for ordering? I'll say - a random. So the final ordering will be random too.

Comment: @Akina if I take CreatedDate than distinct will not work, because as you said earlier the data of row will not be duplicated and the result will be same with duplicate CompanyID.

Comment: I know. It is a reason why DISTINCT is not applicable in your task. The solution can be `SELECT (some fields without CreatedDate) FROM (dataset) GROUP BY (all fields from output list) ORDER BY MIN(CreatedDate)` (or by MAX(), or even by AVG()). But you MUST decide what value from all possible must be used for sorting.

Comment: @Akina, Amazing man, you are the champ thanks for you valuable time, the MAX thing solve the issue with groupby.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

By [@Akin](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/150107/akina)'s help I make this query

```
SELECT c.CompanyID,  c.`CompanyName`, c.`CompanyCode`, c.`URLPart` FROM `company` c
JOIN reports r ON r.CompanyID = c.CompanyID
WHERE r.ProductServiceID= 14 AND c.RegionID=1 AND c.IsActive = 1
GROUP BY c.CompanyID
ORDER BY MAX(r.`CreatedDate`) DESC
```

which solve the issue.

Thank you very much @Akin.

Comment: I'd recommend you to use `GROUP BY c.CompanyID,  c.CompanyName, c.CompanyCode, c.URLPart`. This will not decrease performance, but will avoid the problem with "not full group by" error if you'll change SQL mode of your server or 'll update its version in future.

Comment: @Akina thanks man, I thought it will take extra time, will change sure.
thanks again.